# Flutter share plugin not working

Tags: dart, flutter

I followed the instructions from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share, adding the dependency running `flutter packages get`, but I can't import the plugin in my Dart code. I get the following error:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:share/share.dart'.
```

I tried it a few times, so it's neither a typo nor a singe time bug.

Is this a known bug? And is there any fix for that?

Otherwise is there a different way of sharing simple urls and text pieces in Flutter?

Comment: Have you used "Packages get"?

Comment: You could also try to `Invalidate caches and restart` if you are using Android Studio/IntelliJ. `flutter clean` may also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalidate caches and restart did work, thanks for the help!